# Using an External (custom) Table in a Custom Report

Tags: civireport, database, mysql, custom-reports

I have several custom tables that I have created for use with extensions that I have built.

I would like to use those tables in a custom report. What is the best approach for this? I checked the documentation and did not see anything clear.

I appreciate any direction for this!

Answer (score 3):

Check out an example here - this is a report that joins tables the extension creates/maintains with other civicrm core tables to produce this report:

https://github.com/jake-mw/CDNTaxReceipts/blob/master/CRM/Cdntaxreceipts/Form/Report/ReceiptsIssued.php

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything special you need to do. In your report code you just reference them the same way you do in your extension.